# chrome...addListener, how to wait for chrome.storage.sync.get?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My extension is modifying some URLs. It worked fine, but now I want to check if modifying is enabled in the settings or not.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener
(
    modifyUrl,
    {urls: ['http://somewebsite/*'], types: ['main_frame']},
    ['blocking']
);
```

The problem is that I do not know how to wait for the value. I must get the setting before exiting `modifyUrl`. Is this possible? If this were C#, I would probably have used `ManualResetEvent` or something after calling the `sync.get`.

```
function modifyUrl(details)
{
    chrome.storage.sync.get("someSetting",
          function (data)
          {
            //I can get the setting here
          }
    );

    //how to know the setting here?
    if(enabled in the setting)
    {
        return {redirectUrl: some different url};
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need a callback or promise to wait for the async operation, and *then* return from the function

Comment: Here's an idea -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/69pskkad/

Comment: @adeneo What if the setting changes after you register the event listener?

Comment: @adeneo Chrome seems to load the background script only once, so if I read the setting first and then add the listener, if the user changes the setting after that, the script is not called again... or if there is any way to reload the background script when the setting is changed, I do not know.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you. I will use that 'caching' method. I tried that 'Swapping` approach before posting this question. As I wrote above, the script was called only once, so I could not swap the handler. Could you copy your comment to an answer, so that I can select it as the accepted answer? That may be helpful for future users who might encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Returning Chrome storage API value without function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38456419) for detailed explanations.

In short, a `blocking` onBeforeRequest event is synchronous so it can't depend on asynchronous functions such as all chrome.* API callbacks to derive its return value.

Cache the data in a global variable, and use [chrome.storage.onChanged](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#event-onChanged) to update it when changed elsewhere, which can easily happen if you use chrome.storage.sync (it's updated on profile sync).

```
var settingEnabled; // a global variable
chrome.storage.sync.get("someSetting", function (data) {
    var settingEnabled = data.someSetting;
});

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    modifyUrl,
    {urls: ['http://somewebsite/*'], types: ['main_frame']},
    ['blocking']
);

function modifyUrl(details) {
    if (settingEnabled) {
        return {redirectUrl: 'http://example.com'};
    }
}

chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, area) {
    if (area == "sync" && "someSetting" in changes) {
        settingEnabled = changes.someSetting.newValue;
    }
});
```

Of course, in case you want to disable processing completely, simply detach the listener:

```
function toggleListener(enable) {
    if (enable) {
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
            modifyUrl,
            {urls: ['http://somewebsite/*'], types: ['main_frame']},
            ['blocking']
        );
    } else {
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(modifyUrl);
    }
}

chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, area) {
    if (area == "sync" && "someSetting" in changes) {
        toggleListener(changes.someSetting.newValue);
    }
});

chrome.storage.sync.get("someSetting", function (data) {
    toggleListener(data.someSetting);
});
```

Another interesting approach is to [re-attach onBeforeRequest inside storage.get callback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18579032) on updates.